# The number of partitions [100000] relevant to the query is too large

Tags: sql, database, dolphindb

I execute the following script in dolphindb.

```
select count(*) from pt
```

It throws an exception.The number of partitions [100000] relevant to the query is too large. Please add more specific filtering conditions on partition columns in WHERE clause, or consider changing the value of the configuration parameter maxPartitionNumPerQuery.

How to change the configuration parameter maxPartitionNumPerQuery?

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `maxPartitionNumPerQuery` namely specifies the maximal number of partitions a query can involve. It is designed to prevent users from submitting a large query by accident. The default value for this parameter is 65536. Please configure the new value in cluster.cfg